# DocuSign SOAP Expirations not being set

Tags: c#, soap, docusignapi

I am using the SOAP API in DocuSign using C#.
On an envelope, I am trying to set expiration date to the end of 2016. Per DocuSign support, the max allowed is 999. But when I look at the envelope in correct mode on the web site, I do not see the date being set. Our company has it set to 90 days and that's the expiration date I see.

```
DocuSignAPI.Envelope envelope = new DocuSignAPI.Envelope();
envelope.EnableWetSign = false;  
envelope.AllowReassign = false;
DocuSignAPI.Expirations exp = new DocuSignAPI.Expirations();
exp.ExpireEnabled = true;
exp.ExpireAfter = "128";
exp.ExpireWarn = "0";
```

Comment: That was a user error - i had defined another variable ex and was using that one without setting any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                        DocuSignAPI.Notification ntf = new DocuSignAPI.Notification();
                    envelope.Notification = ntf;
                    DocuSignAPI.Reminders rem = new DocuSignAPI.Reminders();
                    DocuSignAPI.Expirations exp = new DocuSignAPI.Expirations();
                    envelope.Notification.Expirations = exp;
                    exp.ExpireEnabled = true;
                    exp.ExpireAfter = totDays.ToString();
                    exp.ExpireWarn = "0";
```